# Select box only showing last record in drop down in php

Tags: php, forms

I have a drop down box and it only showing the last record in the database I have more than one record in my table.I would like it to display all the records. The script is in a function.

```
function appear(){
include('includes/x.php');
include('includes/y.php');
 global $database;
 $database = new MySQLDatabase();
 $sql="SELECT * FROM tbltype";
 $result_set=$database->query($sql);
    while($row=$database->fetch_array($result_set)){
                        $type=$row['type'];                         

$place= "Please enter type: "." ".'<select name="type" id="type"><option value="-1">Select a province</option><option value="none">None</option>'.'<option value='.$type.'>'.$type.'</option>'.'<br></select>'."<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Add\" value=\"Add\" style=\"border:dotted;\"/>";}   
return $place;
}
```

Comment: your are overwritung the select box. Leave the concatenation of options inside the loop and move rest out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
while($row=$database->fetch_array($result_set)){
                    $type=$row['type'];
                    $option .="<option value='".$type."'>".$type."</option>";
}
$place= "Please enter type: "." ".'
<select name="type" id="type">
   <option value="-1">Select a province</option>
   <option value="none">None</option>'.
   $option.'</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can glean from your code, the problem is your dropdown
declaration is inside your while function, what you should do is declare your

```
<select>
```

tag outside your while, and leave the

```
'<option value='.$type.'>'.$type.'</option>'
```

block inside your while and close your

```
 </select>
```

outside your while function, that way it'll populate your dropdown with the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating properly. Try this,

```
$place = 'Please enter type: <select name="type" id="type"><option value="-1">Select a province</option><option value="none">None</option>';

while($row=$database->fetch_array($result_set)){
       $type=$row['type'];                         

       $place .= "<option value='".$type."'>".$type."</option>";
 }   
 $place .= "<br></select><input type=\"submit\" name=\"Add\" value=\"Add\" style=\"border:dotted;\"/>";

return $place;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function appear() {
        include('includes/x.php');
        include('includes/y.php');
        global $database;
        $database = new MySQLDatabase();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbltype";
        $result_set = $database->query($sql);
        $place = "";
        $place.= 'Please enter type:<select name="type" id="type"><option value="-1">Select a province</option>';
        while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
            $type = $row['type'];
            $place.='<option value="none">None</option>' . '<option value=' . $type . '>' . $type . '</option>';
        }
        $place.='</select><input type=\"submit\" name=\"Add\" value=\"Add\" style=\"border:dotted;\"/>';
        return $place;
    }
```